# Jenkins diamond dependency with 3 upstream jobs triggers only 2 times

Tags: jenkins, dependencies

We have one jenkins job (A) that triggers 3 other jobs (B1,B2,B3).
These 3 jobs all trigger the same job (C).
When triggering job A, the job C is executed twice (I expected 3 times).

**Question: Can someone please explain why C is triggered twice rather than 3 times?**

**Dependencies overview:**

```
  -> B1 ->
A -> B2 -> C
  -> B3 ->
```

The downstream build view shows that 2 of the jobs (for example B2,B3) trigger only one execution of C. Please note that these are not always the same 2 jobs.

Execution overview (Downstream build view of A)

```
  -> B1 -> C (build number 1)
A -> B2 -> C (build number 2) 
  -> B3 -> C (build number 2)  <<< same as for B2
```

**More details about the job configs:**

Job  A has Post-build Actions/Build other projects: B1, B2, B3

Job C has Build trigger/Build after other projects are built/Projects to watch: B1, B2, B3

Jenkins version: 1.583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way how Jenkins triggers jobs. If concurrent builds are not allowed in C (I suppose they aren't), then the following happens:

1. A finishes and triggers B1,B2,B3
2. B1 (for example, could be B2 or B3 as well) finishes and triggers C, build #1 (C#1).
3. B2 finishes and triggers C. The build is stacked since C#1 is still running.
4. B3 finishes and triggers C. As long as C#1 build is running, other builds are stacked and if they are triggered the same way (i.e. C is not parameterized build or parameters are the same), the stacked builds are merged into one. Thus, only one build of C (C#2) keeps stacked.
5. C#1 finishes and the next build in the queue (C#2) is started. As C#2 was merged (from triggers B2,B3), the build queue is now empty.
6. C finishes C#2.

As you can see, C was only run twice.

There is a **workaround**, though. Make C parameterized and supply different values (for example job name of the trigger). Or allow concurrent builds of C - but you must ensure it won't access the same shared resource (e.g. by critical section exclusion).